# Can I disable the unhandled exception handler for a process?

Tags: windows, sap-gui, windows-error-reporting

I am performing system tests on a SAP system. From time to time, SAP crashes and I'd like to recover from those crashes by resetting the virtual machine to a previously saved state.

My problem is that I cannot detect such crashes reliably. I have created WER LocalDumps registry entries, but I don't get dumps.

It seems SAP has registered an unhandled exception handler and performs different tasks on different types of exceptions. Sometimes it shows a message box and terminates the application (e.g. in case of compression errors), sometimes it goes with a so-called Short Dump.

I am neither interested in the message box, nor in the short dump, so I am looking for a way to disable the unhandled exception handler of SAP. This should bring up WER, which writes the dump file and I can take actions to restart my system tests.

For performance reasons, I'd not like to restart the VM on every test.

I have tried:

- I am basically familiar with unhandled exception handlers. I have applied them to my own .NET code successfully.
- I looked at [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and similar but it applies to the calling process only and I cannot modify the code of SAP.
- I read about *DisableUserModeCallbackFilter* but I don't think it is helpful for my case

I wonder whether there is a Registry Setting (e.g. in ImageFileExecutionOptions) or a [Shim](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that I could activate.

Comment: The basic problem is that SAP calls SetUnhandledExceptionFilter().  And does its own thing, all large programs do this.  There is no boss override switch built into the operating system to stop it from doing this.  Maybe SAP has one, use a telephone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s comment (which I take as an authorative answer),

> There is no boss override switch built into the operating system to stop it from doing this.

I finally attached the debugger to SAP GUI at a time where the process was alive. Starting with all exceptions enabled, I narrowed down the conditions so that WinDbg would break when SAP GUI crashed (first chance, then second chance).